# CALayer animation bottom to top

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, swift3, xamarin.ios

I have requirement to animate progress of webservice call using group animation(both text change, layer change) over UIImageView as below.

However adding layer on top of UIImage always appears from top. The required visual wanted to be achieved is shown below. [image]

Comment: Rather than using a `CALayer` I would use a `UIView` with a translucent background color and animate the top constraint constant to the top of your image view.  Put a `UILabel` in the view and change the text as required.  Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: I tried this approach as well, however it also started appearing from Top.

Comment: The you have a problem in your code. Show some code

Comment: It's working now. Some mistake at my end.. Thanks @Paulw11